# What is the difference between ActivityMainBinding.inflate and DataBindingUtil.setContentView?

Tags: android, kotlin

There are two ways to get a binding object when dataBinding is enabled.
The first is

```
val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
setContentView(binding.root)
```

and the second way is

```
val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)
```

which does the binding and setContentView in one call. Other than the reduction in one line, is there any other reason, I should use DataBindingUtil method?

Comment: The `DataBindingUtil.setContentView()` method provides the parent `ViewGroup` when inflating the layout, so any `layout_*` attributes you might have on the root `<View>` will be respected. With the other method, those attributes will basically be ignored. It usually doesn't matter for most common setups – e.g., just `layout_width` and `_height`, both `match_parent`, which is the default anyway – but if you were to need `layout_margin*`s, for example, you'd want to use `DataBindingUtil.setContentView()`.

Comment: The first doesn't use data binding, just view binding.  If you aren't using data binding, that's the form you'd use.

Comment: For `viewBinding` instead, you can effect the same behavior manually, if needed, by doing `ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, window.decorView.findViewById(android.R.id.content), false)`. Just FYI.